# if one of several strings are in other string: return a value + matching string, Python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I would like to ask your help with an "if statement" inside a function that I am using to aggregate some data in a dataframe. With this function I wanted to check if any of several strings are in other string in one column of my dataframe to return an specific value and the matching string.

This is what I have so far and it does what I need. For example, if `"f"` and `"k"` are in my string (`"fk"`), once I apply my function on this row (`find_string("fk")`), my function will return `"success"`.  Additionally I would also like to have the string that was found in the list, in this case `'f'`. Something like `"success" + "f"`

```
 def find_string(b):
     if "a"  in b or "c"  in b or "d"  in b or "f"  in b:
         return "success"  ## here I want to get the matching string
```

Any suggestion?

I am using python 2.7.13 with pandas library.

Comment: You mention a Dataframe, does the answer you are looking for need to pandas-specific? IF so, could you provide a small sample of your dataframe? There are functions/methods in `pandas` that are much faster than normal loops

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pandas, use `str.extract` + `np.where`, it's much faster.

```
v = df['yourCol'].str.extract('([acdf])', expand=False)
df['newCol'] = np.where(v.isnull(), '', 'success' + v.astype(str))
```

Comment: Nice solution :)

Comment: @jezrael Thank you sir, appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_string(b):
   for c in ['a', 'c', 'd', 'f']:
       if c in b:
           return 'success ' + c
   return 'failure'

>>> find_string('fk')
'success f'
```

Comment: This is a pandas question, and a pandas solution is required.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have fixed the OP code. A pandas solution such as yours is _better_, but this answer should still help the OP, which seems to be struggling with a plain Python implementation. (BTW the `pandas` tag was added by me).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use set intersections. It doesn't require any `if` or loops and should be very efficient:

```
>>> set('try to find a substring') & set('acdf')
{'a', 'f', 'd'}
>>> set('no substring') & set('acdf')
set()
```

If you really want to use pandas, look at @Coldspeed's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47075981/6419007).

Comment: This is the "right" way (in plain Python) but there's a step lacking for getting from the set to a `"success f"` or something similar, and it can be confusing for a beginner - what do I do with more than one? with zero? These questions are swept under the rug in the `for` implementation.